# Can't run a war file from new tomcat installation

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, war, vaadin7

I'm having a lot of problems running a war file directly from tomcat. I've checked out a few answers here on stackoverflow but I'm still unable to do it. 
This is what I've done. 
I have an installation of tomcat which I'm using with Eclipse, but I thought I'd create a separate installation somewhere else C:\tomcatTest\apache-tomcat-8.0.39, just so I can play around with the config files without affecting the tomcat instance I use with eclipse. I changed the port to 8099 in the server.xml file and pasted my war file (vaadin.test.jdk7-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in C:\tomcatTest\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps. Now according to the instructions I've found, I start the server up by double clicking on startup.bat and then navigate to http://localhost:8099/vaadin.test.jdk7 but all I get is a "The site can't be reached" error (even if I use the full file name). I've also tried the same procedure within the original tomcat installation, the one I use with eclipse, but no joy. Is there anything else I should be trying that I'm not aware of in terms of configuration?
thanks

**EDIT**
OK guys, after a lot of digging I think I got to the root of the problem. Basically, the server isn’t starting, and the reason for it is an UnsupportedClassVersionError – see screenshot [image] – which occurs when I attempt to start the server. Now, I looked inside the catalina.bat file and it says, among the other things:

```
:use_jdk
echo Using JAVA_HOME:       "%JAVA_HOME%"
:java_dir_displayed
echo Using CLASSPATH:       "%CLASSPATH%"
```

which is great. Checking my environment variables I have my JRE_HOME pointing to 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\Common\Java5.0\jre` not sure why.
Then my CLASSPATH points to 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;` which is right and my PATH variable to 
`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;…C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;` which is not right, so I’ll remove java 8 from the PATH – as I can’t have 2 java versions in it – my question is about the JRE_HOME, can I happily ignore it or should I change that to 1.7 too?

Comment: Can you access the tomcat manager app?

Comment: Could you send the output of your `logs/catalina.out` file?

Comment: Right, @mba12 I've never heard of that before. I had a quick look and I seem to understand that the manager app needs to be configured? I thought doing it manually (ie starting and shutting down the server manually was easier.)
@eztam, I just checked inside the `C:\tomcatTest\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\logs` folder but it's empty, there is no log

Comment: OK got more details. As said I changed the port to 8099 and started the server but if I check the port on the windows prompt `netstat -a -n | findstr :8099` I get no results, so either the server isn't starting (by double clicking on startup.bat) or there is some other problem

Comment: OK updated thread with more details of the problem

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I managed to resolve the issue.

1)make sure that all the Environment variables point to the same JDK (including JRE_HOME!), for instance:

JRE_HOME:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` 

CLASSPATH:
`…C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;`

PATH:
`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;…C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;…`
2)Change the tomcat port if there is any conflict in the server.xml file otherwise leave the 8080 default
3)make sure you uncomment a user in \conf\tomcat-users.xml and give it a meaningful password like so:

```
<tomcat-users...
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="tomcat"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

And the `UnsupportedClassVersionError` goes away and the servers starts successfully.
The lesson from this is that you need to configure your env variables correctly.